# processkv or keyval package keys does not allow 0 key

Tags: packages

Either the processkv or keyval package does not seem to allow the 0 key. When I do 0=val I get errors when trying to process the key but when I do 1=val everything works.

Any ideas?
In parcolumns it processes the keyvalues using:

```
\expandafter\processkeyvalues\expandafter{\the\toks@}\pc@setsinglecolwidth%
```

and the key is simply defined as

```
\define@key{parcolumns}{colwidths}{\toks@{#1}}
```

Which calls calls the following macro to act on the key-value pairs:

```
\def\pc@setsinglecolwidth#1#2{%
    \@ifundefined{pc@column@width@\number#1}{%
        \PackageError{parcolumns}{`#1' is not a valid column width number!}{\@ehc}%
    }{%
        \csname pc@column@width@\number#1\endcsname=#2\relax%
    }%
}
```

The error message is from the package error. It is not creating the `\pc@column@width@0` value for some reason but all other positive values work(well, up to the number of columns).

The way I understand the code is `processkv` simply processes each key-value pair and calls the macro, in this case `\pc@setsinglecolwidth`, on each key-value pair. Hence I see no reason why '0' doesn't work. Since I couldn't find anything in parcolumns that is treating 0 as special I see no reason why the error would be in parcolumns (hence the only other place would be `processkv` and `keyval`?

Works:

```
\begin{parcolumns}[nofirstindent,distance=0pt,colwidths={1=30pt}]{6}%
```

Doesn't Work:

```
\begin{parcolumns}[nofirstindent,distance=0pt,colwidths={0=30pt}]{6}%
```

Comment: No problems for me with a couple of short test cases, which is not so surprising as there is no special meaning to keys. Any chance of a short example of how you are setting things up?

Comment: Really you have asked enough questions to know the score by now, saying "I get errors" doesn't help, please cut and paste the exact error message you get, and show the code that produces the error. Historically since the beginning of computing the most common reason for getting an error just for `0` is that either the definition or use accidentally used `O` instead.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Um, seriously? You do realize that tex does not give exact error messages 99% of the time? As I have said, 1 works but 0 doesn't... usually this means something is wrong with the processing. If it works for you and not me then most likely it will allow me to narrow down the issue. Those with more knowledge about tex's inner workings should be able to understand why 0 would cause such a weird problem. Basically you want me to give you more information which I didn't really have until joseph said it worked for him(which mean's it's probably not processkv.

Comment: @JosephWright I'll post the code where it is most likely an issue then.

Comment: "Um, seriously? You do realize that tex does not give exact error messages 99%" you may think they are not exact, but you are mistaken. If you posted the error message many people would know exactly what bit of latex produced the message, even if the text does not appear relevant, knowing where in the code the error is generated is most often the largest part of debugging.

Comment: "Basically you want me to give you more information which I didn't really have until joseph said it worked for him" Joseph only had that information because he took the trouble to generate a minimal example that just set and used a `0` key. _You_ should have generated that MWE. _Often_ when constructing a MWE to ask a question you discover the problem goes away, which means that the problem is not where you thought it is, so that allows you to generate a different MWE that _does_ show the problem, and ask a more useful question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I looked at the code and there should be no reason why 0 should not work, you know this. Look at my updated answer. There are only 2 possibilities where the error could be: Either in parcolumns or in processkv/keyval. I have looked for the possible error in parcolumns in it is no where to be found. There are only a few lines where it deals with the key. NOW, being that it is an issue with 0 I figured it may be because 0 would not be allowed as a key for some stupid reason. Similarly why some arrays start an an index of 1 instead of 0 and 0 is invalid for them.

Comment: You haven't shown the error message you get and you haven't posted an example that anyone can run to test.

Comment: Using `\toks@` like this looks pretty risky to me: it's a scratch toks which is used in all sorts of places. Without a group, you can't be sure that `\toks@` is not changed between the point where you set it and the point where you use it. Do you see the same issue with a private toks (say `\newtoks\mytoks@` and then using `\mytoks@`)?

Comment: Not knowing much about processkv or keyval my best guess is that the problem lies somewhere with it. When I looked at processkv I saw some comparisons of the key with empty and maybe 0 is the same as empty. I figured I would toss the question out to make more progress than keep beating my head against the wall. Maybe if I did a test case I would have saw 0 worked BUT it would have taken me 30m to type one up since I don't know exactly how processkv works. I would hope that someone much more knowledgeable about it wouldn't mind pointing me in the right direction or solving the problem directly

Comment: @DavidCarlisle IMO I have given enough information if the problem is simple. Normally, in a structured programming language, which such a direct error it would be a rather straightforward solution(90% of the time) and any experienced person could either quickly find the issue or have a pretty good guess at the problem.

Comment: but presumably parcolumns labels its columns 1,2,3...s o why would you expect pc@column@width@0 to be defined? That is, it is presumably nothing to do with keys, just that a 2 column document has columns 1 and 2 I would guess.

Comment: @JosephWright no go ;/

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, my logic is simply this: `\expandafter\processkeyvalues\expandafter{\the\toks@}\pc@setsinglecolwidth%` processes the key-values, right? and for each one it calls pc@setsinglecolwidth to generate a register for each key? So after the processing I should end up with the set of registers `pc@column@width@n` that have the appropriate values(that had keys n). Does this make sense?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is nothing to do with the key mechanism. Just that the columns are labelled 1,2,3... so you can not set the width of column 0.

Comment: I don't undestand this. You say the columns are labelled 1,2,3 BUT where? I don't see parcolumns labeling or creating the column width registers before hand. They are programmatically created. I could create a key using "alpha=30" pt. and it should create a corresponding width register for it(it just won't be used later down the code... but I shouldn't get the packageerror in setcolumnwidth

Comment: You might be right because the ifundefined in `setcolumnwidth` is testing the register and it doesn't exist... but I never saw those registers being created.

Comment: @Uiy I guess David is looking at the `parcolumns` documentation where is says 'Sets the widths of the columns. The widths are specified as key-values, ⟨columnnumber⟩=⟨width⟩. Columns start at ‘1’. Note that in order to be ignored by the keyval package, the complete value has to be surrounded by braces, i.e. ‘colwidths={1=2cm,3=5cm,4=2cm}’ to set the first column to a width of 2 cm, the third to 5 cm and the fourth to 2 cm. (the second column is calculated)'.

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, he is right!! ;/ Sorry. There is the alloccolumns that creates those registers using a counter, which doesn't start at 0.

Answer (score 2):

(An extended comment, really.) With the somewhat hacked-up test file

```
\RequirePackage{keyval,processkv}
\makeatletter
\define@key{parcolumns}{colwidths}{\toks@{#1}}
\define@key{parcolumns}{nofirstindent}[true]{}
\define@key{parcolumns}{distance}{}
\def\pc@setsinglecolwidth#1#2{%
    \@ifundefined{pc@column@width@\number#1}{%
        \PackageError{parcolumns}{`#1' is not a valid column width number!}{\@ehc}%
    }{%
        \csname pc@column@width@\number#1\endcsname=#2\relax%
    }%
}
\newenvironment{parcolumns}[2][]{%
  \setkeys{parcolumns}{#1}%
  \expandafter\processkeyvalues\expandafter{\the\toks@}\pc@setsinglecolwidth%
}
{}
\expandafter\newdimen\csname pc@column@width@0\endcsname
\expandafter\newdimen\csname pc@column@width@1\endcsname
\begin{parcolumns}[nofirstindent,distance=0pt,colwidths={0=30pt}]{6}%
  \expandafter\showthe\csname pc@column@width@0\endcsname
  \expandafter\showthe\csname pc@column@width@1\endcsname
\end{parcolumns}

\begin{parcolumns}[nofirstindent,distance=0pt,colwidths={1=30pt}]{6}%
  \expandafter\showthe\csname pc@column@width@0\endcsname
  \expandafter\showthe\csname pc@column@width@1\endcsname
\end{parcolumns}
```

I see no difference in behaviour other than the expected difference in assignment. As I've commented on the question, my suspicion here is an issue with using the scratch toks `\tok@`, but it's hard to be sure without a full example where I could trace the register through.

Comment: I've modified the tokens but same problem. David maybe right... I'll have to look through the code to find out where those registers are being generated.